# IOS7 - Mapkit and heading

Tags: ios7, mapkit, heading, mkusertrackingmode

I play around the `Mapkit` and want to rotate the map follow user's heading. It works with this function:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    _mapView.centerCoordinate =userLocation.location.coordinate;
    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading;
}
```

However, the moment I rotate the map with 2 fingers and it is gone forever. The beam is not there anymore. I add a button to trigger the `heading`:

```
- (IBAction)showHeading:(id)sender {
    [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
}
```

But it seems like it is not working.

What I want to do is the map is always rotate to user heading no matter what I do. Any suggestion will be good for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it sounds like you want the user tracking annotation features provided by MapKit (the "beam"), you are going to have to either somehow use `MKUserTrackingMode` or else manually recreate the annotation details yourself.

I don't have a good sense as to how you could use the tracking mode, since any pan/pinch/rotate gesture (which presumably you want) will disable tracking mode.

But for recreating, I would look into either [`SVPulsingAnnotationView`](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVPulsingAnnotationView), which gets you partway there, or else the [Mapbox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk), which gives you full control over this sort of thing.